# how can I copy an array from a class and double the size of the new array?

Tags: c++, arrays, copying

```
CDCatalogue::CDCatalogue() //creates array of size 4
{
    maxsize=4;
    numcds = 0;
    cds = new CD[maxsize];
}
```

I want this to copy `cat` into a new array with double the size of `cat`:

```
CDCatalogue::CDCatalogue(const CDCatalogue& cat)
{


}
```

Comment: Easy answer.  Use `std::vector<CD>` and drop the code you're doing now.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested before I'd prefer to use std::vector, which offers the resize() member function for exactly what you need. This is probably what you are looking for.

If for some reason you cannot use vectors, maybe a simpler approach than having a "doubler copy constructor" would be having a function 'doubleSize' that you can call right after construct-copying.

Assuming that in your example in the question, maxsize and cds are declared as class members, you could do something like this:

```
CDCatalogue::doubleSize() {
    unsigned int oldMaxSize = maxsize; 
    maxsize *= 2;  // You might want to keep an eye for overflows here
    CD *oldCds = cds;
    cds = (CD*) new CD[maxsize];
    std::copy(oldCds, oldCds+oldMaxSize, cds);
    delete[] cds;
}
```

Note that this is not as simple as using vectors, because there is no "resize" for c++ dynamic allocations. Instead, you have to create a new array of the new desired size, copy the elements of the old array into the new, and then release the memory of the old array. Note that the last half of elements of the new array will be initialized to undefined values.